# How can i add line break in custom label in lightning component | Salesforce

Tags: lightning, customlabel

want to write some text in different line as i google it then found some way, 
where they told to add  make sure escape=”false”
[image]

but this is not working for me 
 {!$Label.c.forgot_password_content}

any idea how to do it in lightning component or have to use three separate custom label for it?

Comment: You can use 'aura:unescapedHtml', be aware that it opens up XSS security issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sanitizing global string attributes - necessary or not?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185519/sanitizing-global-string-attributes-necessary-or-not). Refer Mohit's answer.

Comment: there is an answer for this question, and the duplicate indication is not correct
answer is - use `lightning-formatted-rich-text` component and the label with html element '<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

Let us save the label as below :

Thanks & Regards,#sfdcsrini.blogspot.com Team#Testing by sfdcsrini.blogspot.com

Now we can split the above label using '#' on initialization of component as below:

```
var testLabel = $A.get("$Label.c.Test_With_Line_Breaks");
var labelArr = new Array();
if(testLabel && testLabel.includes("#")){
     labelArr = testLabel.split("#");
     component.set("v.labelArr",labelArr);//set desired component attribute & use it to display
}
```

It is set as an array since it can be helpful to use and even change order of text.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Please let me know the reason for downvote , this is a standard way to access and split label in lightning.

Comment: I expected some decency from this community but maybe i'am expecting too much. Anyway , thanks for the feedback.